# How to add import option to our custom module

Tags: import, csv, entities

I have created new custom module with the admin form like to create new Products. I have created successfully.All are working fine.But now i want to add one more feature to this module. I can import products through CSV files under **system/import/export**, which is a default Magento feature.

Like this how should I import my fields through CSV files.I have no idea about, how to do this task.

Under **system/import/export**, we have entity type **"Products and customers"**. If I add my entity similar to this, is that enough; or do I have any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

To use the import/export module for custom entities, you will have to extend it properly. You will need to create your own import entity which handles the import.
Then you would do the import from the backend exactly like for products, but you select your entity.

To help you get started, refer to this module where a custom import entity is created to be able to import categories:

https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/blob/master/src/app/code/community/AvS/FastSimpleImport/Model/Import/Entity/Category.php

Similarly, you can do it for your custom entity.

Comment: Thank you for your response.shall i need to add any xml file rather than this?

Comment: Is it possible to import custom models (flat models)

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```